# My div is aligning to the left even when my body text-align is set to center. (Details provided below)

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` element that aligns to the left, although my body sets `text-align` to `center`. I experimented and noticed only when my `<div>` has `width` set in the `style` attribute, it aligned to the left. How do I make my `<div>` align correctly while having a `width`?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="text-align: center">
    <div style="width: 200px">
      This div aligns to the left.
    </div>
    <div>
      This div aligns properly.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div` is a block level element and `text-align` centers the text within and not the div itself.

change to

```
<div style="width: 200px;margin: 0 auto">
   This div aligns to the left.
</div>
```

`margin:0 auto` sets top and bottom margin to 0 (update if necessary) and equally distributes the margin to left/right.

Technically, the second `div` also does not align center, the reason you see it centered aligned is because the `div` takes up the full width of its parent as it is a block level element, and the text within is center aligned.

Because you're restricting the `width` on the first `div`, it is on the left, however the text within it will still be center aligned.

Comment: "text-align does not have any affect on it." it does have an effect! it centers the text within the div. it does not center the div.. just clearing that out

Comment: @Aziz oops! Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to center something is the one mani mentions, but you could also set the `text-align` property for the div's container and set the div's `display` as `inline`. The div would act like text inside the div container. Personally I prefer to use `margin: 0 auto;` to get things centered, but it's good to know that it's not the only way.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/foumuedv/

*As you can see I had to add an extra `<br/>` because inline elements don't add a line break.

Answer (score -1):

having the style seperate has solved the issue

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

  <body>
    <div>
      This div aligns to the left.
    </div>
    <div>
      This div aligns properly.
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```